# Как создать свой тип данных в c++

Tags: c++, xcode

У меня есть строка: string str_Word;
Мне нужно присвоить i-ому символу значение русской букву, но вот незадача: русский символ в кодировке utf-8 занимает 2 байта(вроде байта), а один элемент строки вмещает в себя 1 байт (тоже вроде), нужно создать свой тип переменной чтобы я мог поместить русский символ туда. Если есть другое решение проблемы также пишите.

Comment: Ну присвойте два элемента строки. А вообще для полноценной работы с юникодом придется использовать надлежащую библиотеку типа ICU.

Comment: Как вариант, используйте два байта под каждый символ (UTF-16).

Comment: …или стандартный `wstring`, правда об удобствах utf-8 стоит забыть и поиметь ещё с десяток своеобразных проблем... Но опыт это особый...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Поделитесь, чем же utf8 удобней wstring?

Comment: @Cerbo, обратной совместимостью и, как следствие, распространённостью... да, ужасный аргумент, но такова жизнь...

Comment: wstring не слышали?

Answer (score 0):

С C++11 в строках можно использовать префикс u8.
Например:

```
std::string hello = u8"Привет!";
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264818/storing-unicode-utf-8-string-in-stdstring).

Если всё же нужен тип данных, способный вместить в себя два байта, используйте wchar_t. Соответствующая строка - std::wstring, подобные литералы имеют префикс L (как в `L"Привет!"`).